# Examples of line_search in scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I'm searching for examples of using `scipy.optimize.line_search`. I do not really understand how this function works with multivariable functions. I wrote a simple example

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize
def test_func(x):
    return (x[0])**2+(x[1])**2

def test_grad(x):
    return [2*x[0],2*x[1]]

sp.optimize.line_search(test_func,test_grad,[1.8,1.7],[-1.0,-1.0])
```

And I've got

```
File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\linesearch.py", line 259, in phi
return f(xk + alpha * pk, *args)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: [1.8,1.7],[-1.0,-1.0] should be of type ndarray; does it help casting them as numpy arrays? Also why don't you use the functions real gradient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to submit numpy arrays instead of lists:

```
import numpy as np
sp.optimize.line_search(test_func,test_grad,np.array([1.8,1.7]),np.array([-1.,-1.]))
```

Comment: You talk about numerical value of grad or about test_grad funct?

Comment: I talk about the gradient function. Computing the derivatives should completely remove the square terms. Edit: I see you fixed it.

Comment: Main question is, why alpha is scalar, not ndarray? Reading about Wolfe conditions, I thought, that alpha have to be same dimensionality as xk.

Comment: No, alpha is the step length. The pk that you give as an argument is the vector. Check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_conditions) for details.

Comment: It correct for one variable function. But if we want to minimise f(x,y), x,y - both vectors(matrices) with different lenght (dimensionalities)?

Comment: You might be looking for [scipy.optimize.minimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). line_search is only intended to solve a part of that problem. If you have problems with that, try asking a new question. And feel free to accept my answer if it answered the current question.