# Issues with scipy line-search

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to use the scipy function [line_search](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.line_search.html), but I get an error, which doesn't make sense to me. Probably I am doing somenthing wrong. My goal is to do a line-search for a function f that maps matrices to the real numbers.

I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011343/examples-of-line-search-in-scipy) but unfortunately, applying the solution there doesn't solve my problem, although the author there wants to do something similar with vectors instead of matrices.

I've prepared an easy toy-example.

```
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import line_search

def fct(x):
    return x[0,0]**2+x[1,1]**2

def grad(x):
    return np.array([[2*x[0,0],0],[0,2*x[1,1]]])   

start = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
direction = np.array([[1,1],[0,1]])

result = line_search(fct,grad,start,direction)
```

The error-message reads as follows:

```
File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\linesearch.py", line 429, in scalar_search_wolfe2
    if (phi_a1 > phi0 + c1 * alpha1 * derphi0) or \
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It seems like the error occurs in a subroutine of line_search_wolfe2, which is called when I call line_search. Obviously, the value in the line where the error occurs, isn't scalar valued. I took a look in the source, but I couldn't find any reason why this value isn't scalar, as intended.

What is wrong with my input?
Do I get anything wrong in the definition of the line_search function?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but nearly everything in scipy.optimize assumes `x` to be **1d** and things break a lot if that's not the case due to hidden flattenings. When people prefer defining things on matrices, they usually need to accept the fact, that x is assumed to be 1d and do the `1: reshape 1d -> nd, 2: process nd, 3: reshape nd -> 1d 4: return`  workflow. Simpe example in the [code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py#L278) this looks scary when the dimenion of `xk` is not constrained.,

Comment: As @sascha said, this really arises because your function returns an array. Looking [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/adc4f4f7bab120ccfab9383aba272954a0a12fb0/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py#L384), you can see that the line search routine expects your function to evaluate to a scalar, so that the comparison that fails in your question is always acceptable.